# Alfresco SDK run seems stuck at "Processing overlay"

Tags: maven, alfresco

I use the Alfresco SDK with the following command:

```
mvn install -Ddependency.surf.version=6.3 -Prun
```

All is fine, except when it gets stuck at this step of `Building Alfresco Share WAR Aggregator`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ share ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [share] in [/home/nico/aegif/projects/60_townpage/townpage-filing/townpage-filing/share/target/share-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[info] Copying manifest...
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.alfresco:share]
```

In such cases I just perform a clean and the problem is solved, but that takes time.

Is there anything I can do to avoid it getting stuck?

alfresco.version is 5.1.g
Ubuntu 2016.10 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the parameters you are using, I assume you are on Alfresco SDK 2.2, and trying to use a more recent version of alfresco (5.1.f or newer) on a All In One project.

Using Alfresco SDK AIO projects always adds some overhead during restarts because the SDK is actually building your modules, fetching the wars, fetching additional modules referenced and applies the modules to the wars (as in unzipping the war and unzipping the amps on the same folder before re-packaging the wars), then it starts up an embedded tomcat with some special config from the runner project with the new wars! A complicated approach, if you ask me, and it is definitely expected to take a considerable amount of time and performance (especially on Disk IO), especially when you clean before you rebuild... 
Back to your question, the step you are hanging on if when the SDK is trying to unzip the OOTB share war prior to applying amps to it, and there is a lot of reasons why things could go south there! And unless you rovide some more detailed steps (as in adding -X or -e to your mvn command) I doubt  any one would be able to catch precisely what is going wrong !

Be careful with running your project without cleaning, as you might end up with some risidual files that give you a different behaviour from the one to be expected from final artifacts... I can imagine at least a couple of these scenarios !

Alternatively, may I suggest that you switch from AIO approach to seperate projects for Repo and Share ? You can install multiple tomcats on your machine: Let's say a tomcat for repo on port 8080 and a tomcat for share on 8081, then you can develop on one tier while having a tomcat service provide the other one (Stop the share tomcat service, and start up a share amp from the SDK pointing to the local Alfresco Repo service on the the other locally installed tomcat) that way you can rapidly always clean and run with this command for running share:

`mvn clean install -PampToWar -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081 -Ddependency.surf.version=6.3`